# Do brackets (parentheses) change the order of methods?

Tags: java, parentheses

In a similar way to 'proper' mathematics, does using brackets change the order of methods.

For example,

```
System.out.println(Math.abs(Math.min(-6,3)));
```

gives the output 6. Is this because the math.min does its job before the absolute value is calculated?

I want to make sure that this is the case and it's not come quirk of the maths class.

Thank you

Comment: *Is this because the math.min does its job before the absolute value is calculated?* Yes.

Comment: and is this always the case in Java and not only the maths class?

Thank you

Comment: There's nothing special about `Math` methods. They are just methods, like any other methods in any other class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not the consequence of parenthesis ordering. While it's true that parenthesis can be used to specify the order of operations while working with operators this is a matter of syntax.

A method invocation in Java is done through `methodName(arguments)`, this means that you couldn't express what you are trying to express in a different way. Such parenthesis are not used to express precedence, but they are really part of the syntax of the language.

Since a method requires its arguments to be evaluated before the call happens, `Math.min` must be evaluated before `Math.abs`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using chained/nested method calls changes the order of methods. The method on the very inside will be executed first, then the method around that, and so on. The inside method must be evaluated first so that the method around it actually has a value to be passed as an argument. If the method chain started from the outside, the first method's arguments/parameters would not be evaluated, so the computer would not know what value to pass to that method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Math.min is calculated first followed by the Math.abs. The rules you learned on your Mathematics class also applies in programming.

```
Math.abs(Math.min(-6,3));
Math.abs(-6);
6
```